# Why can't a genetically sound human stay alive for an indefinite amount of time given all the ideal conditions?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, senescence, life, lifespan

I have read that even if we can control our food and lifestyle and keep things as ideal as possible, there are other factors beyond our control like effects from neutrinos passing through our body that would accumulate over time, and may cause harm. More over, Earth's natural radiation, and the Cosmic background radiation may as well play a part.

I wonder what if we somehow removed these as well, will one be able to live forever?!
I have heard people say that this is an impossibility, but I wonder why?!

Thanks.

Comment: Your telomeres will kill you long before neutrinos do.

Comment: What exactly are telomers @AlexReynolds?...are they the chains at the end of a polymer or something like that?

Comment: Related questions: [Why does evolution not make our life longer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/why-does-evolution-not-make-our-life-longer) and [Is it possible for a human to live forever if he/she didn't catch any diseases?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67531/is-it-possible-for-a-human-to-live-forever-if-he-she-didnt-catch-any-diseases)